# Entity Framework Code First MySQL longblob Data Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have to recreate an existing MySQL table in my Entity Framework Code First Model

It has a column defined as a "longblob"

What type should I define this as in my model please?

Comment: It is byte[] for longblob

Comment: you  are correct. please add that as an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Daniel, It is byte[] for longblob.

May be this link will be useful to reference

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/DataTypeMapping.html